# Highcharts - how to color spider chart areas by group value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts with spider chart option and I'm interested in filling chart areas with a certain color, based on a common value of the items that are included in the graphic.

The chart shows item values, but the items should be grouped by colors (c1, c2) based on the group value which can be found within the object that I'm using. Each item has a group.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use multiple series to create it, because zones are not able to draw spider partially.

```
series: [{
    name: 'Allocated Budget',
    data: [43000, 19000, 60000, 35000, 17000, 10000],
    pointPlacement: 'on'
},{
    name: 'Allocated Budget',
    data: [43000, 19000,0],
    pointPlacement: 'on'
}]
```

Demo:

- http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4t62xv6u/